# How to Launch a Script from Any Directory with Python

Tags: python, macos, terminal, command-line-interface

Currently, in order to launch all my python scripts from the terminal I have to go to the relative folder and use

```
$ python myscript.py
```

to launch the script. How can I make it so that I can just type

```
$ myscript
```

to launch that script, no matter what folder I'm currently in?

Comment: Depends on your operating system. Please tag your question accordingly.

Comment: If you're a Linux user check the last part there: http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/app_c.html#making-a-python-script-executable-and-runnable-from-anywhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using linux/macos

1. add this shebang at the beginning of the script `#!/usr/bin/env python3`
2. make sure you can execute the file by calling `chmod +x myscript.py`

Now if you are in the same directory of the script you can run it simply with the command `./myscript.py`.

To be able to run the script, no matter what directory you are in:

3. move the script into a directory listed inside the `$PATH` environment variable, like `/usr/local/bin`, or make a directory ad-hoc for your scripts and add that dir to the `PATH` variable

You can now call your script by just typing its name in the terminal.

Comment: With `echo $PATH` you can see what dir's are in the path and move the script there

Answer (score 2):

You can use **alias** in your bash_profile for mac or bashrc in linux.

.bash_profile

```
alias myscript="python /<dir_where_file_is_located>/myscript.py"
```

once alias is added then reload it

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Now you can by just type **myscript** and enter.

```
$ myscript
```